# In android application how to add an image overlay in a video

Tags: java, android, video

My app has a requirement wherein a watermark png need to be added to the videos. Is there any sdk or library that helps with this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to 'burn' the image into the video itself and save a new copy with he image then you likely want to use something like ffmpeg - there are Android wrappers available and the sone seems to be the most up to date at the time of writing (I have not used this particular one but have used others successfully):

- https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit

You can add the image with ffmpeg using a command like this:

```js
ffmpeg -i inputVideo.mp4 -i yourImage.png -filter_complex "overlay=5:5" -codec:a copy outputVideo.mp4
```